# Table structure for a quiz based app

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to build a basic quiz app but I am confused about the table structure currently i created two tables `question` & `options` but I am not sure whether to keep them separate or should I merge both of them into a single table. Please advice me for a better structure for my quiz app.

My question table -

[image: question]

My `options` table -

[image: options]

one more thing-- currently no primary key is set for options table as i am not sure about this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd definetely separate the tables - it's more efficient and keeps the structure cleaner. You can also use foreign keys.

But I think it'd be better done this way:

TABLE 1: (questions)

- ID
- Question

TABLE 2: (options)

- ID
- Question's ID
- Option value
- Is correct? (bool)

So you could `SELECT * FROM Options WHERE Question_ID = X`

Comment: your thoughts for second option table? is it fine as no key set for the table ?

Comment: Here, I edited my post to explain it more. It's good practice to set keys on your table - it speeds up requests and avoids having trash entries in your DB. Also, with the structure I provided you can add multiple choice quiz without changing your db structure.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on how your quiz would look like. If you're sure that every question would be "choose one from four" - then you can make one table with columns "good answer", "1st bad answer", "2nd bad answer", "3rd bad answer". It would be easier and pretty efficient.

On the other hand making separate table for options would allow you to make questions with different number of possible answers easily

Comment: It is good, but having in mind that customer will ALWAYS change his mind sooner or later this solution is pretty troublesome ;)